# JavaScriptCore Objective-C Slow When accessing non existing objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, javascriptcore

My app slowed down extremely and I ran some tests to find out why.
I ran it twice, the first time accessing an object that is in the context, and the second accessing a non-existing object in the `JSContext` 
I tracked it down to this part:

```
JSContext *ctx = [[JSContext alloc] init];

[ctx evaluateScript:scpt];
// var someExisting = {"view": {"tint-color": "red"}};

NSDate * start = [NSDate date];

    for (int i=0; i<=100000; i++) {
    ctx[@"someExisting"][@"view"][@"tint-color"];
}

NSDate * end = [NSDate date];

    double timeTaken = [end timeIntervalSinceDate:start] * 1000;
    NSLog(@"%g", timeTaken);
[ctx release];
```

#### I got 195.697

```
JSContext *ctx = [[JSContext alloc] init];

[ctx evaluateScript:scpt];
// var someExisting = {"view": {"tint-color": "red"}};

NSDate * start = [NSDate date];

    for (int i=0; i<=100000; i++) {
    ctx[@"nonExisting"][@"view"][@"tint-color"];
}

NSDate * end = [NSDate date];

    double timeTaken = [end timeIntervalSinceDate:start] * 1000;
    NSLog(@"%g", timeTaken);
[ctx release];
```

#### I got 8377.37! CPU and Memory also spike up

Does anyone know if this is a `JavaScriptCore` bug or something that I'm doing incorrectly?